# Raster dataset doesn't exist error

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.1, error-000865

Dataset exist and I am able to get statistics from ArcGIS python window. But it failed as a script with error:
ERROR 000865: Input raster: C:\temp\ras does not exist.
I have tried following suggestions:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000r000000

but to no avail.Please suggest how to handle this

```
import arcpy

stat = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(r'C:\temp\ras', "MEAN")
avg = stat.getOutput(0)
print avg
```

Comment: I just took your exact code, replaced your raster path with one to a file geodatabase raster (using the raw string input method of r"C:\path to raster"), and it worked just fine as a script run from my IDE (not from within ArcMap).

Comment: your code work for me as script run from cmd and IDE within ArcMap.

Comment: Exactly what is the full name (with path) of your raster? The error message is perfectly clear--it's *not* "c:\temp\ras"!

Comment: It is "ras" and I stated below that after restarting my system, I got it working (reasons aren't obvious to me...maybe a windows thing).

Comment: I had the exact same thing happen to me with AsciiToRaster_conversion. I just restarted the computer and it seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still gave the same error even after removing 'r'.

I restarted the system and it worked both with and without 'r'.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the 'r' in your first argument and try forward slashes instead. It will look like this:

```
stat = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management('C:/temp/ras', "MEAN")
```

The function GetRasterProperties_management takes two arguments. The first being the path of the raster and the second is the property. [Read more about the function here.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000m7000000)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It still gave the same error even after removing 'r'. I restarted the system and it worked both with and without 'r'.

Comment: Interesting solution! Must be a Windows thing.

Answer (score 1):

is "\ras" the folder where the raster is in or is this the raster already?
what format is your raster in?
you could try with ListRasters first and use the result

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\test"
lr = arcpy.ListRasters()
stat = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(lr[0], "MEAN") #use the first raster in the list
avg = stat.getOutput(0)
print avg
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with raster processing. I have noticed that you will have less issues with processing a large number of datasets if you set environment variables arcpy.env.workspace and arcpy.env.extent.