# Error 000865 when using arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, error-000865

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I always get the error 000865 when using  arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion. I'm new and do not have much Python experience right now – so sorry for that.

```
>>> import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\erste_schritte\dritter_tag_python\testdaten"

#folder to list
ascFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.asc")

for ascFile in ascFileList:
# geoprocessing steps
ascFileName = os.path.splitext(ascFile)[0]
# define the output file
rastFile = ascFileName + "_output.img"
# run the tool
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(ascFile,rastFile, "INTEGER")
```

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 15, in         File "c:\programme\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2193, in    ASCIIToRaster     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000865: Eingabe-ASCII-Raster-Datei:    2001002_cloud_free.asc ist nicht vorhanden.

Do I have to use the CatalogPath? I'm working with ArcMap 10.2.1. 
Thanks

Comment: Well your error is that the raster is not present. Does ` 2001002_cloud_free.asc` actually exist? It is a valid file that is recognized by Arcmap?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50592/raster-dataset-doesnt-exist-error). Could be a weird bug.

Comment: The steps under the `for` loop need to be indented -- is it correct in your script? (Often pasting code into Questions loses spaces.)

Comment: Yes, it in the script. I gonna try to fix it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASCIIToRaster tool is not interpreting the file names correctly, despite you setting the workspace environment. You need to include the full path, so in your case your line should be:

```
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(env.workspace + "\\" + ascFile, env.workspace + "\\" + rastFile, "INTEGER")
```

Also as @Erica says you should get into the habit of placing `print` statements in your code to see the actual value of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the raster exists by using a `print` statement, e.g.

```
for ascFile in ascFileList:
    print ascFile
```

If that prints a list of .asc files, [try rebooting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50592/raster-dataset-doesnt-exist-error).

If that doesn't work, check that the ASCII file will convert properly by testing just one (in a separate temporary script).

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(r"c:\temp\2001002_cloud_free.asc",r"c:\temp\outp‌​ut.img", "INTEGER")
```

And use the full file path as Hornbydd describes:

```
for ascFile in ascFileList:
    # define the input file path
    ascFilePath = env.workspace + "\\" + ascFile
    # define the output file
    ascFileName = os.path.splitext(ascFile)[0]
    rastFilePath = env.workspace + "\\" + ascFileName + "_output.img"
    # run the tool
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(ascFile,rastFile, "INTEGER")
```

Comment: So I print every step, did restarted the system, but I still get the same ERROR while running the tool. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: 'print ascFileList
    #works
    for ascFile in ascFileList:
    # geoprocessing steps
    ascFileName = os.path.splitext (ascFile)[0]
    print ascFileName
    #works
    rastFile = ascFileName + "_output.img"
    print rastFile
    #works
    #run the tool
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion (ascFile, rastFile, "INTEGER")
    #ERROR 000865'

Comment: @Nora Try (in a new script, perhaps) running the tool on just one raster with explicit declaration, e.g.: `arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(r"c:\temp\2001002_cloud_free.asc",r"c:\temp\output.img", "INTEGER")`

Comment: it works with just one:                                                             ASCII inASCII = r"D:\Julia_T\2000067_cloud_free.asc"
    outRaster = r"D:\Julia_T\output"
    rasterType = "INTEGER"                                                     arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(inASCII,outRaster,rasterType)

Comment: Good, so the raster files are not the problem. Try using the full path as Hornbydd proposes in his answer.

Comment: still error 000865:                                                              `    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion (env.workspace +        r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\erste_schritte\dritter_tag_python\testdaten" + ascFile, env.workspace + r"D:\Julia_T\projekt\erste_schritte\dritter_tag_python\testdaten" + rastFile, "INTEGER")`

Comment: See edits above

Comment: I can't believe it – it works and you find the way awhile   ago and I did't understand it. Thanks so much. Now I have to add all the other tools...THANKS                                          `` arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(r"c:\temp\2001002_cloud_free.asc",r"c:\temp\outp‌​ut.img", "INTEGER")